# Sonarqube plugin installation using netrCreds

Tags: sonarqube, amazon-eks, .netrc, sonarqube-plugin

We are installing Sonarqube as a self managed service via the helm charts at https://SonarSource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube.. Sonarqube instance was working fine but we did a change to use netrc type Credentials to download plugins from JFrog artifactory after which our pods started failing.

- Log details can be found as below

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl logs sonarqube-sonarqube-0 install-plugins -n sonarqube
sh: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/downloads/sonar-pmd-plugin-3.3.1.jar: unknown operand
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
bash-3.2$ kubectl exec sonarqube-sonarqube-0 -n sonarqube -- ls /opt/sonarqube/extensions/download 
Defaulted container "sonarqube" out of: sonarqube, init-sysctl (init), concat-properties (init), inject-prometheus-exporter (init), init-fs (init), install-plugins (init)
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("sonarqube")
```

```
NAME                    READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
sonarqube-sonarqube-0   0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   525        44h
```

```
Name:         sonarqube-sonarqube-0
Namespace:    sonarqube
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-10-110-198-195.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.110.198.195
Start Time:   Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:31 +0200
Labels:       app=sonarqube
              controller-revision-hash=sonarqube-sonarqube-6d6c785f6f
              release=sonarqube
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=sonarqube-sonarqube-0
Annotations:  checksum/config: 823d389fbc2ce9b41133d9542232fb023520659597f5473b44f9c0a870c2c6a7
              checksum/init-fs: ad6cbc139b1960af56d3e813d56eb450949be388fa84686c48265d32e68cb895
              checksum/init-sysctl: 3fc2c9dee4de70eed6b8b0b7112095ccbf69694166ee05c3e59ccfc7571461aa
              checksum/plugins: 649c5fdb8f1b2f07b1999a8d5f7e56f9ae65d05e25d537fcdfc7e1c5ff6c9103
              checksum/prometheus-ce-config: b2643e1c7fd0d26ede75ee98c7e646dfcb9255b1f73d1c51616dc3972499bb08
              checksum/prometheus-config: 3f1303040aa8c859addcf37c7b82e376b3d90adcdc0b209fa251ca72ec9bee7e
              checksum/secret: 7b9cfd0db7ecd7dc34ee86567e5bc93601ccca66047d3452801b6222fd44df84
              kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.110.202.249
IPs:
  IP:           10.110.202.249
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/sonarqube-sonarqube
Init Containers:
  init-sysctl:
    Container ID:  docker://3e66f63924be5c251a46cf054107951f5056f23a096b2f6c8c31b77842e0f29d
    Image:         leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox@sha256:20142e89dab967c01765b0aea3be4cec3a5957cc330f061e5503ef6168ae6613
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -e
      /tmp/scripts/init_sysctl.sh
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:42 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:42 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        20m
      memory:     64Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp/scripts/ from init-sysctl (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
  concat-properties:
    Container ID:  docker://b04f51eaa84bf4198437c7a782e0d186ea93337ac91cc6dae862b836fc6ef6a9
    Image:         leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox@sha256:20142e89dab967c01765b0aea3be4cec3a5957cc330f061e5503ef6168ae6613
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      #!/bin/sh
      if [ -f /tmp/props/sonar.properties ]; then
        cat /tmp/props/sonar.properties > /tmp/result/sonar.properties
      fi
      if [ -f /tmp/props/secret.properties ]; then
        cat /tmp/props/secret.properties > /tmp/result/sonar.properties
      fi
      if [ -f /tmp/props/sonar.properties -a -f /tmp/props/secret.properties ]; then
        awk 1 /tmp/props/sonar.properties /tmp/props/secret.properties > /tmp/result/sonar.properties
      fi
      
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:43 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:43 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        20m
      memory:     64Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp/props/sonar.properties from config (rw,path="sonar.properties")
      /tmp/result from concat-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
  inject-prometheus-exporter:
    Container ID:  docker://22d8f7458c95d1d7ad096f2f804cac5fef64b889895274558739f691820786e0
    Image:         leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/curlimages/curl:7.76.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/curlimages/curl@sha256:fa32ef426092b88ee0b569d6f81ab0203ee527692a94ec2e6ceb2fd0b6b2755c
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
    Args:
      curl -s 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.16.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.0.jar'  --output /data/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar -v
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:43 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:44 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     20m
      memory:  64Mi
    Environment:
      http_proxy:   
      https_proxy:  
      no_proxy:     
    Mounts:
      /data from sonarqube (rw,path="data")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
  init-fs:
    Container ID:  docker://2005fe2dbe2ca4c5150d91955563c9df948864ea65fca9d9bfa397b6f8699410
    Image:         leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/busybox@sha256:20142e89dab967c01765b0aea3be4cec3a5957cc330f061e5503ef6168ae6613
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -e
      /tmp/scripts/init_fs.sh
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:44 +0200
      Finished:     Sat, 10 Sep 2022 13:57:44 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        20m
      memory:     64Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /opt/sonarqube/data from sonarqube (rw,path="data")
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions from sonarqube (rw,path="extensions")
      /opt/sonarqube/logs from sonarqube (rw,path="logs")
      /opt/sonarqube/temp from sonarqube (rw,path="temp")
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /tmp/scripts/ from init-fs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
  install-plugins:
    Container ID:  docker://58a6bed99749e3da7c4818a6f0e0061ac5bced70563020ccc55b4b63ab721125
    Image:         leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/curlimages/curl:7.76.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/curlimages/curl@sha256:fa32ef426092b88ee0b569d6f81ab0203ee527692a94ec2e6ceb2fd0b6b2755c
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -e
      /tmp/scripts/install_plugins.sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    22
      Started:      Mon, 12 Sep 2022 10:53:52 +0200
      Finished:     Mon, 12 Sep 2022 10:53:56 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  525
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     20m
      memory:  64Mi
    Environment:
      http_proxy:   
      https_proxy:  
      no_proxy:     
    Mounts:
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions/downloads from sonarqube (rw,path="extensions/downloads")
      /opt/sonarqube/lib/common from sonarqube (rw,path="lib/common")
      /root from plugins-netrc-file (rw)
      /tmp/scripts/ from install-plugins (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
Containers:
  sonarqube:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/sonarqube:9.5.0-developer
    Image ID:       
    Ports:          9000/TCP, 8000/TCP, 8001/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     4
      memory:  6Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      1
      memory:   4Gi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:http/api/system/liveness delay=60s timeout=1s period=30s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [sh -c #!/bin/bash
# A Sonarqube container is considered ready if the status is UP, DB_MIGRATION_NEEDED or DB_MIGRATION_RUNNING
# status about migration are added to prevent the node to be kill while sonarqube is upgrading the database.
host="$(hostname -i || echo '127.0.0.1')"
if wget --proxy off -qO- http://${host}:9000/api/system/status | grep -q -e '"status":"UP"' -e '"status":"DB_MIGRATION_NEEDED"' -e '"status":"DB_MIGRATION_RUNNING"'; then
  exit 0
fi
exit 1
] delay=60s timeout=1s period=30s #success=1 #failure=6
    Startup:  http-get http://:http/api/system/status delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=24
    Environment Variables from:
      sonarqube-sonarqube-jdbc-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      SONAR_WEB_JAVAOPTS:        -javaagent:/opt/sonarqube/data/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8000:/opt/sonarqube/conf/prometheus-config.yaml
      SONAR_CE_JAVAOPTS:         -javaagent:/opt/sonarqube/data/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8001:/opt/sonarqube/conf/prometheus-ce-config.yaml
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'password' in secret 'sonarqube-database'>                                       Optional: false
      SONAR_WEB_SYSTEMPASSCODE:  <set to the key 'SONAR_WEB_SYSTEMPASSCODE' in secret 'sonarqube-sonarqube-monitoring-passcode'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /opt/sonarqube/conf/ from concat-dir (rw)
      /opt/sonarqube/conf/prometheus-ce-config.yaml from prometheus-ce-config (rw,path="prometheus-ce-config.yaml")
      /opt/sonarqube/conf/prometheus-config.yaml from prometheus-config (rw,path="prometheus-config.yaml")
      /opt/sonarqube/data from sonarqube (rw,path="data")
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions from sonarqube (rw,path="extensions")
      /opt/sonarqube/logs from sonarqube (rw,path="logs")
      /opt/sonarqube/temp from sonarqube (rw,path="temp")
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n89wf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-config
    Optional:  false
  plugins-netrc-file:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  eks-prv-0001-maven-local-default
    Optional:    false
  init-sysctl:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-init-sysctl
    Optional:  false
  init-fs:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-init-fs
    Optional:  false
  install-plugins:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-install-plugins
    Optional:  false
  prometheus-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-prometheus-config
    Optional:  false
  prometheus-ce-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sonarqube-sonarqube-prometheus-ce-config
    Optional:  false
  sonarqube:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  sonarqube-sonarqube
    ReadOnly:   false
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  concat-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-n89wf:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                     ----     -------
  Normal   Pulled   29m (x521 over 44h)      kubelet  Container image "leaseplan.jfrog.io/docker-hub/curlimages/curl:7.76.1" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff  4m39s (x12224 over 44h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```